# How to debug why cookie is not being set with setcookie on one server but works on other?

Tags: apache, cookies, setcookie, php-5.4

I have included a form which takes user's input and sets a cookie with setcookie php function while processing the form.

This works in one server, but doesn't work on other.

The server in which the cookies isn't working shows some blank httponly cookies in client's browser.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this..I can see form values are successfully being submitted in POST, but I don't know what's happening when it runs setcookie.

And yes, I am setting the cookie in before html and in headers.

My php is custom installation and is of 5.4.45 and httpd version is 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

This was set in my httpd.conf file causing cookie to not work:

```
Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure
```

I don't know the consequences of disabling it. But I have disabled it anyway temporarily, until I know what they are for.